# How to get the enum file name at runtime based on backend parameters?

Tags: java, enums

I have four enum files in java for eg: A.java ,B.java ,C.java . 
Now my requirement is I have a parameter let us say filename , if I get the filename parameter as A then it will execute file of A.java ,i.e A.Red similarly with the other cases.
Filename will come from restAPI.

I am trying with an interface i.e I created an interface and implements it on all enums and trying to catch the enum reference in interface but the problem with this approach is I cannot create enum instance .
This is what I have tried :

```
String enumClassName = "enums.A";   
Class c = Class.forName(enumClassName);
//System.out.println(c.);
Object obj = c.newInstance();
SystemEnums enums = (SystemEnums)obj;
System.out.println(enums.getEnumType().get(0));
```

Here SystemEnums  in an interface.

```
A.java
enum A{
Red,Blue
}


B.java
enum B{
Yellow,Black
}


C.java
enum C{
Pink,White
}
```

Comment: Where SystemEnums in your code? Would you mind to put all the relevant code in the question?

Comment: What is the *purpose* of this approach? What is the problem you intend to solve this way?

Comment: You know, just for the record: if all enums represent something similar, why are there 3 enums, and not just one?

Answer (score 2):

What about some kind registry, which knows all available enum types. The registry can then have a method like this: getEnumByName(String enumName).

In my opinion a common interface is not really needed here as you can use standard enums.

See this example:

```
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    EnumRegistry registry = new EnumRegistry();
    registry.registerEnum(A.class);
    registry.registerEnum(B.class);
    registry.registerEnum(C.class);

    final Enum enumByName = registry.getEnumByName("A");
  }
}

enum A {
  Red,
  Blue
}

enum B {
  Yellow,
  Black
}

enum C {
  Pink,
  White
}

public class EnumRegistry {

  private Map<String, Class<Enum>> registeredEnums = new HashMap<?>();

  public void registerEnum(Class e) {
    registeredEnums.put(e.getName(), e);
  }

  public Enum getEnumByName(String name) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    final Class<Enum> enumClass = registeredEnums.get(name);
    if (enumClass != null) {
      return enumClass.newInstance();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No bro , it is giving error saying "A cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: isn't this rather a lot to do to simply get enums?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get enum instances from reflected enum class, just use `values`:

```
package x;

public class EnumTest {

    public enum TestEnum {
        A, B, C
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class<?> enumClass = Class.forName("x.EnumTest$TestEnum");
        Object[] enumInstances = (Object[]) enumClass.getMethod("values").invoke(null);
        for (Object enumInstance : enumInstances) {
            System.out.println(enumInstance);
        }
    }

}
```

Be aware that calling values creates new array each time and can be expensive.